# How to split data in column to draw box plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to draw a box plot splitting data in one column ("var_2" below) into two boxes from this column, based on data in another column ("var_1" below).

Specifically, I have these data (main data frame 1):

```
id  var_1   var_2
A   1   0.13
B   3   0.25
E   5   0.22
F   6   0.43
G   2   0.11
H   4   0.38
```

Then I would like to draw a box plot that has as box 1 the values of var2 corresponding to the bottom half of var_1, so that is the data in data frame 2:

```
id  var_1   var_2
A   1   0.13
G   2   0.11
B   3   0.25
```

Box 2 in the box plot then has the var_2 values corresponding to the top half of var_1, so that is the data in data frame 3:

```
id  var_1   var_2
H   4   0.38
E   5   0.22
F   6   0.43
```

How can I do this in R, please? I would ideally use ggplot2 with/without tidyverse. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the values into top and bottom using `ntile(var_1, 2)`.

Assuming data frame named `mydata`:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata  %>% 
mutate(q = factor(ntile(var_1, 2))) %>% 
ggplot(aes(q, var_2)) + 
geom_boxplot()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Terrific, thank you so much for your quick solution.

Comment: You're welcome, please vote for and accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Done both. I am just too junior for the +1 to be shown.